# Impact of holding non-TT positions on potential for a TT position

Tags: job, tenure-track, non-tenure

Is there any (negative) effect of prior holding of one or more non-tenure-track (TT) positions on the potential of being hired (and promoted) at a TT position at a university (mostly interested in US)?

Comment: ... as opposed to being hired into TT position from the scratch.

Comment: Now, I saw that title and wondered why Academia SE was talking about racing on the Isle of Man.

Comment: You mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isle_of_Man_TT)? Sorry, I didn't know about that thing before your comment. Otherwise, I would likely choose another topic to limit your potential surprise :-)

Comment: What kind of non-TT position?  Teaching oriented?  Research oriented professor?  Postdoc?  Industry?  Something else?  For how long?  What kind of TT position?  What kind of university?  R1 university?  One with more of a teaching mission?  Please provide more detail, as the answer will likely depend upon these factors, and trying to cover all possible cases would require too long of an answer.  In general, if your question is only one sentence, that's often a good indication that it would be helpful to flesh it out: it will help you get better answers, and make it more useful to others.

Comment: @D.W.: Thank you for clarifying questions (+1). Mine is thought as a more of a general question, as I was trying to capture various types of situations. I agree with you that those factors should have been stated, if known. Unfortunately, I had no specific circumstances in mind for this particular question. Having said that, the answer by Brian Borchers is quite nice and provides a good _starting point_ for thinking about the topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In many academic fields it has become the norm for new PhDs to work in post-doc, visiting assistant professor, or other temporary non tenure-track positions before moving into a faculty position.  This is normal and expected. It should be obvious how a research post-doc will help you to gain experience in research.  For new PhDs with limited teaching experience, a good visiting assistant professor position can help with gaining teaching experience.

However, there's a difference between a research oriented post-doc and a long term full time (or worse part time) non tenure track position as a lecturer.  In the latter case, you will have little opportunity to continue working on research and may be put to work teaching very low level courses.  It can be very hard to work up from such a position into a tenure track position, and the longer you do it, the worse it will look on your resume.

Even with good research post-docs and visiting assistant professor positions, there's a limit to how many years you can do this work before you'll be seen as having failed in your academic career.  Too many years of post-doc experience is worse than having too little experience.

Comment: Thank you for such an excellent answer - detailed and very clear. Much appreciated (+1 and accepted).

Comment: Related mini-question, based on one of your points above: could a postdoctoral position (at an excellent university), affiliated with a project lasting more then 2-3 years, be damaging to one's academic career?

Comment: Five year grants are about the longest planned projects that I've ever seen,  It's wouldn't be unusual to budget for a post-doc position for the whole 5 years of such a grant, but I wouldn't plan to have the same person in the position for that whole five years.  As a post-doc working on such a long term project you should be careful to make sure that there are ample opportunities to publish results during your time as a post-doc and not just at the very end of the project.

Comment: I appreciate your clarification. Thanks to it, I have a clearer understanding now.